# JBoss WindUp and Sonarqube

Tags: migration, sonarqube

im looking for a simple way to integrate [JBoss Windup](http://windup.jboss.org/) Reports into [Sonarqube](http://www.sonarqube.org/) to track migration efforts over many modules

Is there anything in progress ?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I don't know from the Sonarqube point of view.
But there's a Maven Windup plugin under (re-)development which will allow you to run the analysis as a part of a Maven build.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. The maven plugin helps a lot in my scenario. Unfortunately there is no plugin for sonar yet. May its time to develop my own plugin :-)

Comment: Let the Windup team know if you decide to develop the plugin, We will gladly cooperate, if time allows.